# Updating a sliced array also updates the larger array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need an explanation for something weird that I noticed with array slicing (NodeJs)

```js
const a = [{ x: 1 }, { x: 3 }, { x: 4 }];
const b = a.slice(0, 2);

for (let input of b) {
  input.y = 1;
}

console.log(b);
console.log(a);
```

The output has the array a as well as array b updated, even though in the for loop, I am only updating the elements in array b. What am I missing here?

Edit: I tried looking this up as well as went through the MDN Docs for 'slice' but could unfortunately not find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

> The slice() method returns a ***shallow copy*** of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from start to end

So basically it creates a new array but the selected elements will still be the same, here are the same references of the objects

You could check it like this by comparing

```js
const a = [{ x: 1 }, { x: 3 }, { x: 4 }];
const b = a.slice(0, 2);

console.log(a[0] === b[0])
console.log(a[1] === b[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I guess as I read the MDN Docs, I didn't fully understand what a 'shallow copy' means. That was the missing piece of the puzzle for me. Now I do understand it a bit better.

As an additional point, I was also curious about the case you pointed out in @HR01M8055 answer below i.e. if I have a nested object.
With my new understanding of shallow copies, I looked it up a bit and found that a combination of JSON.stringify & JSON.parse creates a completely deep copy

const b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a)).slice(0,2);

Answer (score 1):

`Array.slice` creates a copy of the array, so `a !== b`, but since `a` is made out of objects, `b` still retains the references to those identical objects.
So any change you make to the objects in one array, also affects the other array.

You have to deep copy `a` if you want `b` to contain entirely new objects.

Answer (score 1):

when you use slice you will get a new array but the `objects` are same that are in `a`. If you want to add properties without affecting object on `a` then you should clone the objects.

**Remember:** Below code snippet will work if there is no nested objects

```js
const a = [{ x: 1 }, { x: 3 }, { x: 4 }];
const temp = a.slice(0, 2);
const b = [];

for (let obj of temp) {
  const o = { ...obj };
  o.y = 1;
  b.push(o);
}

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: `const o = { ...obj }` would help in this case but still a shallow clone, won't work if the object is `{ x: 1, y: { z: 1 } }`

Comment: This is not the nested object case that's why I've used `spread syntax`